# case insensitive xpath searching in php

Tags: php, xpath

I have an xml file like this:

```
<volume name="Early">
<book name="School Years">
<chapter number="1">
<line number="1">Here's the first line with Chicago in it.</line>
<line number="2">Here's a line that talks about Atlanta</line>
<line number="3">Here's a line that says chicagogo </line>
</chapter>
</book>
</volume>
```

I'm trying to do a simple keyword search using PHP that finds the word and displays the line it was in. I have this working

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($data);
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
$kw=$xml->xpath("//line[contains(text(),'$keyword')]");
...snip...

echo $kw[0]." is the first returned item";
```

However, using this technique, a user *must* search for 'Chicago' and not 'chicago', or the search will return nothing.

I understand I need to use the translate function but all my trial and error has been in vain.

I've tried:

```
$upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$kw = $xml->xpath("line[contains(text(),'translate('$keyword','$upper','$lower'))]");
```

but nothing seems to work. any tips?

Comment: You seem to have an extra single quote in front of `translate` in your last code example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gordon's recommendation to use a PHP function from within XPath will prove more flexible should you choose to use that. However, contrary to his answer, the `translate` string function **is** available in XPath 1.0 so that means you can use it; your problem is **how**.

First, there is the obvious typo that Charles pointed out in his comment to the question.  Then there is the logic of how you're trying to match the text values.

---

In word form, you are currently asking, "*does the text contain the lowercase form of the keyword?*" This is not really what you want to be asking. Instead, ask, "*does the lowercase text contain the lowercase keyword?*"  Translating (pardon the pun) that back into XPath-land would be:

<sup>(Note: truncated alphabets for readability)</sup>

```
//line[contains(translate(text(),'ABC...Z','abc...z'),'chicago')]
```

The above lowercases the text contained within the `line` node then checks that it (the lowercased text) contains the keyword `chicago`.

---

And now for the obligatory code snippet (but really, the above *idea* is what you really need to take home):

```
$xml    = simplexml_load_file($data);
$search = strtolower($keyword);
$nodes  = $xml->xpath("//line[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '$search')]");

echo 'Got ' . count($nodes) . ' matches!' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($nodes as $node){
   echo $node . PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

**Edit** after [dijon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238989/case-insensitive-xpath-searching-in-php#comment-3357213)

Inside the foreach, you could access the line number, chapter number and book name like below.

**Line number** -- this is just an attribute on the `<line>` element which makes accessing it super-easy. There are two ways, with SimpleXML, of accessing it: `$node['number']` or `$node->attributes()->number` (I prefer the former).

**Chapter number** -- to get at this, as you rightly said, we need to traverse up the tree. If we were using the DOM classes, we would have a handy `$node->parentNode` property leading us directly to the `<chapter>` (since it is the immediate ancestor to our `<line>`). SimpleXML does not have such a handy property, but we can use a relative XPath query to get it. The [parent axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) allows us to traverse up the tree.

Since `xpath()` returns an array we can cheat and use `current()` to access the first (and only) item in the array returned from it. Then it is just a matter of accessing the `number` attribute as above.

```
// In the near future we can use: current(...)['number'] but not yet
$chapter = current($node->xpath('./parent::chapter'))->attributes()->number;
```

**Book name** -- the process for this is the same as that of accessing the chapter number. A relative XPath query from the `<line>` could make use of the [ancestor axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) like `./ancestor::book` (or `./parent:chapter/parent::book`). Hopefully you can figure out how to access its `name` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of how it works, in addition to the code snippet. Exactly what I was looking for! I have been using mainly simpleXML for this project but it's nice to have Gordon's answer below to compare.

Comment: One thing I would LOVE to know :) is within that foreach clause, How would I also go about listing the line-number, chapter-number and book name? I believe this is also xpath based on current node and navigating up the tree?

for instance, (from first XML example) I'd like to search for 'atlanta' and receive:
  
School Years, Chapter 1: Here's a line that talks about Atlanta.

once again, trial and error has been tying me in knots!

Comment: thanks again! Since I'm working with simpleXML I never would have stumbled upon the 'current()' "cheat" as you call it. I knew about the axes but could never figure out how to describe the starting point. I always appreciate getting an explanation along with code. That way I learn something!

Answer (score 3):

See salathe's answer on how to do it with SimpleXml and translate().

As an alternative/added option to using XPath functions, you can use any PHP function as of PHP5.3, including self defined, in XPath Expressions when using [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). I am not sure the same is available in SimpleXml.

```
// create a DOMDocument and load your XML string into it
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

// create a new Xpath and register PHP functions as XPath functions
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xPath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xPath->registerPHPFunctions();

// Setup the query
$keyword = 'chicago';
$q = "//line[php:functionString('stripos', text(), '$keyword')]";
$nodes = $xPath->query($q);

// Iterate the resulting NodeList
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will output

```
Here's the first line with Chicago in it.
Here's a line that says chicagogo
```

For more details, see [@salathes blog entry](http://cowburn.info/2009/10/23/php-funcs-xpath/) and [the PHP Manual.](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php)

Comment: +1 for hinting at being able to use PHP-land functions within XPath queries (and linking to my blog!). :)

Comment: @salathe out of curiosity: do you know if there any function that would allow me to use the DOMNodeList like I would use an array in array_map or an iterator in iterator_apply? Short of using `$xpath->query('//book[php:function("callback", author)]');`?

Comment: "I am not sure the same is available in SimpleXml." - not directly, but there is nothing to stop folks mixing and matching DOM/SimpleXML classes. :)

Comment: @Gordon('s comment) - You could wrap the `DOMNodeList` in an `IteratorIterator`, and use `iterator_apply` on that.

Comment: @salathe I did say that? Wow? When? Being 30+ is a pain. You forget things constantly. :D

Comment: Thanks for this Gordon, I used salathe's response above but you've given me another approach which I will study closely!

Answer (score -1):

I may have missed something... but here's another approach that is IMHO - simpler. 
How about using PHP's `strtolower()` before loading the XML into SimpleXML via `simplexml_load_string()`?

**IE**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(strtolower(file_get_contents($xml_file_path)));
$keyword = strtolower($_GET['keyword']); //Make sure you sanitize this!
$kw = $xml->xpath("//line[contains(text(),'$keyword')]");
```

**This way, you're comparing lowercase::lowercase**