# XPATH query with single quote

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Anyone have any ideas how to resolve this? The single quote is throwing me for a loop.

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath("//item[contains(@catalog,'Billy's Blogs')]/title");
```

I've tried to escape it in various ways, all throwing errors:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath("//item[contains(@catalog,'Billy\'s Blogs')]/title");
$nodes = $xml->xpath("//item[contains(@catalog,'Billy&apos;s Blogs')]/title");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use whatever way there is in your language (I don't know PHP) to escape the quote character inside a quoted string**, something like this:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath("//item[contains(@catalog,\"Billy's Blogs\")]/title");
```

Comment: +1 Good answer addressing the real problem: embbeding a language into other language. Same kind of problems one could have with PHP and EmacScript.

Answer (score 3):

As [salathe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113938/salathe) answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273143/php-xpath-dealing-with-apostrophe-single-quote-in-searched-text/3273435#3273435), you cannot escape an apostrophe in XPath.

Comment: Please do not provide answers of other people in this way. [Or make it a CW](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki). We do not get upvotes for finding duplicates, nor for closevoting (which you cannot do yet).

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I was unaware of the community wiki functionality.

Comment: actually, this is a pretty important point

Answer (score 0):

How about using *quote* along with **'** and **"**? See example in [here](http://extract-web-data.com/xpath-review/#Operators). `notes = 'New Lapytop&quots ;USB&quot; MP3 player&quot'`

Comment: This does not seem valid.