# How to escape all invalid characters from DOM XPath Query?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, html-escape-characters

I have the following function that finds values within a `HTML DOM`;

It works, but when i give parameter `$value` like: `Levi's Baby Overall,`
it cracks, because it does not escape the , and ' chars

How to escape all invalid characters from DOM XPath Query?

```
private function extract($file,$url,$value) {
    $result = array();
    $i = 0;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTMLFile($file);
    //use DOMXpath to navigate the html with the DOM
    $dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $elements = $dom_xpath->query("//*[text()[contains(., '" . $value . "')]]");
    if (!is_null($elements)) {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $nodes = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                if (($node->nodeValue != null) && ($node->nodeValue === $value)) {
                    $xpath = preg_replace("/\/text\(\)/", "", $node->getNodePath());
                    $result[$i]['url'] = $url;
                    $result[$i]['value'] = $node->nodeValue;
                    $result[$i]['xpath'] = $xpath;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: You'll probably find you're answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452323/xpath-query-with-single-quote.

Comment: i don't think is possible, he's code does not work on all DOM's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One shouldn't substitute placeholders in an XPath expression with arbitrary, user-provided strings -- because of the risk of (malicious) XPath injection.

To deal safely with such unknown strings, the solution is to use a pre-compiled XPath expression and to pass the user-provided string as a variable to it. This also completely eliminates the need to deal with nested quotes in the code.

Comment: the whole reason of ESCAPING the string in the first place, is to make sure it has no special meaning in xpath, both  so that hackers can't inject anything to it, and that it can reliably search for exact text strings like `//parent::*[@password]`

Comment: `the solution is to use a pre-compiled XPath expression and to pass the user-provided string as a variable to it.` - uhh, no, that's not a solution in PHP, as PHP's DOMXPath doesn't support variables (just another reason to avoid PHP, i guess)

Comment: @hanshenrik, Yes, I don't know PHP, in .NET one can use the XsltContext class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

PHP has no built-in function for escaping/quoting strings for XPath queries. furthermore, escaping strings for XPath is surprisingly difficult to do, here's more information on why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1352556/1067003 , and here is a PHP port of his C# XPath quote function:

```
function xpath_quote(string $value):string{
    if(false===strpos($value,'"')){
        return '"'.$value.'"';
    }
    if(false===strpos($value,'\'')){
        return '\''.$value.'\'';
    }
    // if the value contains both single and double quotes, construct an
    // expression that concatenates all non-double-quote substrings with
    // the quotes, e.g.:
    //
    //    concat("'foo'", '"', "bar")
    $sb='concat(';
    $substrings=explode('"',$value);
    for($i=0;$i<count($substrings);++$i){
        $needComma=($i>0);
        if($substrings[$i]!==''){
            if($i>0){
                $sb.=', ';
            }
            $sb.='"'.$substrings[$i].'"';
            $needComma=true;
        }
        if($i < (count($substrings) -1)){
            if($needComma){
                $sb.=', ';
            }
            $sb.="'\"'";
        }
    }
    $sb.=')';
    return $sb;
}
```

example usage:

```
$elements = $dom_xpath->query("//*[contains(text()," . xpath_quote($value) . ")]");
```

- notice how i did not add the quoting characters (`"`) in the xpath itself, because the xpath_quote function does it for me (or the concat() equivalent if needed)