# DOMXPath->query(???) to search every node in an HTML document looking for JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, xquery, domxpath

How would one search through a HTML document to find the JavaScript myfunc within it? 
That is, I'd like to find the aforementioned needle in an HTML haystack that may contain the following nodes.

- `<p onMouseOver="myfunc(a,b,c)">blah blah blah</p>`
- `<a href="javascript:MyFunc(a, b, c)">blah blah blah</a>`
- `<img onmouseover='myFunc(a,b, c )' src="someimage.gif">`

The PHP code I am currently using is:

```
foreach($domxpath->query('[onmouseover^="myfunc"]') as $node) {
    $text = $node->nodeValue;
    echo "<br>text=".$text;  // just to see what i get
}
```

Comment: Big ups to [Explosion Pills](http://stackoverflow.com/users/454533/explosion-pills) for correcting my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not just searching for `onmouseover` it seems (look at the `<a>`).  Hopefully the function name is consistent because PHP is only XPath 1.0

```
//*[@*[contains(.,"myfunc")]]
```

This selects any node anywhere with any attribute that contains "myfunc" (case sensitive).

Comment: How would I make this case _insensitive_?

Comment: Try with XPath 2.0 it would be so easy, but I'm afraid there is no simple case insensitive search available.  There is an ugly alternative, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238989/case-insensitive-xpath-searching-in-php

Comment: Pardon, but the solution gives me the node name & value. How do I access the attribute? [getAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) requires the attribute name to be known.

Comment: You can scan `$node->attributes` and do a similar comparison (you've narrowed down the nodes).  If you want to select the attribute node itself, you can use `//@[contains(.,"myfunc")]]` I think

Answer (score 1):

You want a pattern like `//*[contains(@onmouseover, 'myfunc')]`:

- `//*` selects all elements in the document.
- `[contains(@onmouseover, 'myfunc')]` then selects those for which the onmouseover attribute contains "myfunc".